# How to locate the original feature branch after a fast forward merge

Tags: git, merge, atlassian-sourcetree, git-flow, fast-forward

In our team we decided to use a SourceTree for it's very convenient when using [Git-flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). When a feature branch contains one commit only, SourceTree is going to do a "fast-forward" merge into the devlop branch.

When we browse the git commit logs I can't figure out what's the original feature branch of a given fast-forward merge commit.

The only workaround I found is to always have an associated remote feature branch. This way others will be able to see the feature branch name attached to the fast forward commit/

Is there a way to to make it work for local only feature branches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you tell git not to do fast-forward merges?

```
$ git merge --no-ff
```

It will create a new commit even if it resolves the merge as fast-forward.

On SourceTree there is an option in Preferences->git called `do not fast-forward when merging, always create commit`.

I think this option will add `--no-ff` to `git merge`.

Comment: Yes we can do it from git command line. Maybe there is also some global SourceTree config for that too.